# How to check if the user inputs anything other than a number?

Tags: java

Hi so my whole program works fine. I just don't know how to add another else if statement that checks for the user's input. If the user inputs a letter or string, then I want the program to print something like "Please enter a number only". It should be easy to do, but for some reason, I can't seem to figure out. Also one more info I am a freshman in college, so please help me with easy syntax.

Thank you so much.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;


public class Practice1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // These lines welcome the user and prompt them to choose
        // the action they want to do with their account.
        System.out.println("Hello user!");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do with the account?");
        System.out.println("Enter one of the following choices: ");
        System.out.println(" - 1 to check your balance.");
        System.out.println(" - 2 to make a deposit.");
        System.out.println(" - 3 to make a withdrawal.");
        System.out.println(" - 4 to exit the program.");
        System.out.print("Your choice: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");


        // declare a variable that stores our initial balance, deposit and
        // the amount that we'd like to withdraw from our account.
        double balance = 300;
        double deposit;
        double withdraw;
        boolean checkAlp1 = Character.isAlphabetic(choice);

        // initiate a while loop. As long as the user's choice
        // is not the number 4, the loop will continue.
        while (choice != 4) {

            // if the user inputs number 1, then print out his balance.
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Your balance is $" + balance + ".");
            }

//I need help here .........
            else if (checkAlp1) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
            }
            // otherwise, if the user inputs 2, then ask them how much
            //they want to deposit. Store their input in a variable called deposit.
// if the user enters 2, ask them how much they want to deposit.
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
                deposit = input.nextDouble();

                //if the deposit is negative number to zero, then print "Invalid" message.
                if (deposit <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter an amount greater than 0.");
                }
//otherwise increment the balance by how much the user deposits
                else {
                    balance += deposit;
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
//show the balance after updating it.
                System.out.println("Your balance is now $" + balance + ".");
            }
//if the user enters number 3, then ask them how much they want to withdraw
            else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
                withdraw = input.nextDouble();

// if the amount they withdraw is greater than zero and it's less or equal
// to the value of the balance
// then check to make sure there is not only $30 left in the account
//if so, then tell the user not enough funds.
                if (withdraw > 0 && withdraw <= balance) {
                    if (balance - withdraw < 30) {
                        System.out.println("no enough funds");
                    }
//otherwise subtract how much the user wants out of the balance.
//then print out how much the user withdrew.
                    else {
                        balance -= withdraw;
                        System.out.println("You withdrew $" + withdraw + ".");
                    }
                }

// if the amount the user tries to withdraw is less or equal to zero
//print invalid.
                else if (withdraw <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please try again");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
                System.out.println("Your current balance is $" + balance + ".");
            }
// if the user enters 4, then exit the program
            else if (choice == 4) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do with the account?");
            System.out.println("Enter one of the following choices: ");
            System.out.println(" - 1 to check your balance.");
            System.out.println(" - 2 to make a deposit.");
            System.out.println(" - 3 to make a withdrawal.");
            System.out.println(" - 4 to exit the program.");
            System.out.print("Your choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\n");

        }
// print this statement.
        System.out.println("Exiting the program.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go for switch case statement.

```
switch(choice)
case 1:// 1 is value entered in choice
// execution part
break;
case 2:
// execution part
break;
case 3:
// exe part
break;
case 4:
// exe part
break;
default: // here in default mentioned else part
System.out.println("Please enter any number from 1-4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a for loop and check for each character if any characters is greater then equal to character ‘0’ and less than equal to ‘9’.then it’s digit.

Answer (score 0):

`choice = input.nextInt();` this line will throw InputMismatchException if the next input is not a int.
So all you have to do is catch this exception and display the corresponding message.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this without using built in checks is:

```
static boolean isInt(String s){//read s as a string (input.next();)
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(!s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9') return false;
    } 
   return true;
 }
```

Haven't checked this btw but I remember doing this a while ago.